# When using text reference in excel (=A1), how can I get the target cell to autofit it's height according to the content's size?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

When using text reference in excel (=A1), how can I get the target cell to autofit it's height according to the content's size?
I use text references mainly for admission formats, with one "data" page many rows long and some other sheets where it just formats the contents. But anytime the amount of text exceeds the predetermined height I originally set on the Format Sheet, I have to manually adjust each row before printing. Is there any automatic way of fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Select all cells in the worksheet by hitting CTRL+A and then in Home tab > In Cells Group > Click Format > Click AutoFit row data.

Comment: CTRL+A will apply the effect on entire sheet,, ut OP is looking for the TARGET CELL i.e. A1   !!

Answer (score 0):

*You may try this:*

- Select the Cell.
- Resize the column a little wider.
- Double-click a row separator,

*The row height will be auto-fitted.*

*For column width.*

- Double-click a column separator,

*The Column widths will be auto-fitted.*

---

**Another is VBA Macro:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim myTarget As Range

    Set myTarget = Range(Selection.Address) 
    Target.Rows.Select 
    Target.Rows.AutoFit
    myTarget.Select

End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- Use this macro as Standard Module.
- Save the workbook as Macro enabled.
- Select the cell, change font (for height), enter data, leave the cell, you find the effect.